# How to get another fields from "Session with FastAPI Dependency"

Tags: python, fastapi

I am checking FastAPI and have meet a problem. How to get another fields from "Session with FastAPI Dependency"?

I took code from this link https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/fastapi/session-with-dependency/

```
@app.get("/heroes/{hero_id}", response_model=HeroRead)
def read_hero(*, session: Session = Depends(get_session), hero_id: int):
    hero = session.get(Hero, hero_id)
    if not hero:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Hero not found")
    return hero
```

Hero class is declared like this

```
class HeroBase(SQLModel):
    title: str
    description: str

class Hero(HeroBase, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(None, primary_key=True)
    hero_name: str
    content_type: str
    user: Optional[User] = Relationship(back_populates="hero")
    created_at:datetime = Field(default=datetime.utcnow())
```

In the code info about the `hero` can be found by his id - `hero_id`.
But, in my case, i need to find hero by his name- `hero_name`; or another filed. If i change accordingly:

```
hero = session.get(Hero, hero_name)
```

I am getting an error:

```
null
```

This is, definitely not right to do it. I have checked several links about this topic

[Session in FastAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68099561/session-in-fastapi)

[Understanding session with fastApi dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74481604/understanding-session-with-fastapi-dependency)

[FastAPI dependency override faild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71907063/fastapi-dependency-override-faild)

and was not able to find something related.

Thank you for your answers

Comment: This has nothing to do with FastAPI, you have simply not learned SQLModel enough. Here is the [documentation on reading data](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/select/)